# How can I set the duration of a splash screen?

Tags: unity, timing, splash-screen

I am using Unity Pro, so I have all [Splash Screen Tools](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html) available.  I have a full screen image which I want to use as my splash screen.  I want my splash screen to remain on the screen for n seconds.  I want the splash screen to be cropped if it is not a perfect fit to the device's screen size.

The following settings give me the desired results, however the splash screen only stays up briefly, and does not allow me to choose the duration:

[image: Default Splash Screen Settings]
[image: Default Splash Screen Results]

These settings allow for me to set the duration, however the splash screen is just an icon in the middle, and won't "Scale to fill (cropped)", like in the settings above:

[image: Logo Splash Screen Settings]
[image: Logo Splash Screen Results]

I can use a blank image as my logo and add a background image, but it becomes all blurry.  (The darkness goes away if as I change the overlay opacity.):

[image]
[image]

I have tried other variations in the settings, but the three attempts above are the closest I have come.  I have tried removing the splash screen, and creating an empty Scene on launch with just the full-size cropped image, but this causes a delay to launch the app with a bad white flicker.  I have tried using the static splash screen settings in addition to the blank starting scene, but this causes the screen to go black momentarily.

How can I use a full-screen cropped Splash Screen for a set duration?

Comment: You could just use the static splash image or background image for that couldn't you? I don't have access to Unity Pro but it should be possible.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I do not think I understand you.  But if you mean add a static splash screen for the second set of settings, I have tried.  But nothing appears.

Comment: Try the "static splash image" instead? The background image is blurred by Unity.

Comment: @Draco18s that's what I do in my first attempt above. I am trying to set the duration for it.

Comment: The logo gets a duration. The logo does not fill the screen. I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: Have you tried static splash screen with no logo image? Or with a blank image?

Comment: @Candid Moon yes. The static splash​ screen does not show at all

Comment: I'm assuming you are setting a fully transparent image on logo image, right? Have you tried to leave it empty while setting the background? I have no unity pro, so I can't look that is why I'm asking, just throwing some ideas.

Comment: @CandidMoon Yes, I have tried.  Didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Unity Pro, but I've created my own "splash screen" in the past by just using Unity GUI. Then you have complete control.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting, if you want to control the splash screen in a way that is not possible with Unity's settings, doing it manually is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen stays some minimum amount of time plus until the first scene is ready.
Haven't tried it myself yet but what you can possibly do is -using the background image-, you can delay the load of the first scene by X seconds.

Here is the Unity manual link for splash screen:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html

And the section related to your case:

> The entire duration of the Splash Screen is the total of all logos
>   plus 0.5 seconds for fading out. This might be longer if the first
>   Scene is not ready to play, in which case the Splash Screen shows only
>   the background image or color and then fades out when the first Scene
>   is ready to play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative method, where you set the default time to the minimum value, and make the default splash screen reference a black screen. Then, at the start of the scene, use your default splash screen.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it just felt laggy. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: Hi! I cant understand I mean what kind of laggy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have unity pro but I found this and thought that it would help:

[image: Duration]

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html